# Method Defined in Controller Throwing NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, nomethoderror

My application has `Dwellings` and `Roomies`. I am building some authentication into the `Dwelling` view - only `users` who are `roomies` of the current `dwelling` should be able to view certain data - all other users will see a different view.

To enable this, I have created an `is_roomie?` method in the `Users Controller`. The method looks like this:

```
## is_roomie? method in Users_Controller.rb ##

def is_roomie?
roomie_ids = []
@dwelling.roomies.each do |r|
  roomies_ids << r.id
end
roomie_ids.include?(current_user.id)
end
```

I call this method in the `Dwelling` view as follows:

```
## show.html.erb (Dwelling) ##
....
<% if current_user && current_user.is_roomie? %>
....
```

When I loaded the page after implementing this, I get the following NoMethoderror:

> NoMethodError in Dwellings#show
>
> Showing >/Volumes/UserData/Users/jraczak/Desktop/Everything/rails_projects/Roomie/roomie/app/views/dwellings/show.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> undefined method `is_roomie?' for #User:0x00000102db4608>

For some background, I did try this as a `Dwelling` method and moved this into the `User` model to no avail. Thanks in advance for any and all insight!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_user` is a `User` object, not a `UsersController` object, so you cannot call the method you've defined on that object. When you think about it in this context, you'll see that you should define this method on `User`.

Try something like this in app/model/user.rb:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def roomie?(dwelling)
    dwelling.roomies.include?(self)
  end
end
```

Looking at this, though, we can improve the code by moving it into the Dwelling class in app/models/dwelling.rb:

```
class Dwelling < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  def roomie?(user)
    roomies.include?(user)
  end
end
```

You would then use this in the view with:

```
<% if current_user && @dwelling.roomie?(current_user) %>
```

Comment: This works brilliantly. I won't say I completely understand the actual issue described in the first paragraph - namely I don't understand what a UsersController object is - but I'm going to try to read up on it. Thanks for fixing my roadblock.

Comment: At the top of the users_controller.rb, you'll see that the controller is defined as `class UsersController < ApplicationController`. Within that class definition, we define many methods, like `index`, `show`, etc. These methods are _instance_ methods. When Rails routes a request to the UsersController, it creates a new instance of that class. Since you defined `is_roomie?` in the UsersController class, it was an instance method in instances of `UsersController`, but not `User`.

Answer (score 0):

The current_user object does not have a method is_roomie?. This is a method in your controller. You can call the method in your show action and make it available for the view like so:

```
#in UsersController.rb
def show
  @is_roomie = is_roomie?
end
```